Finding the maximum squared distance between a pair of coordinates from a set of coordinates
I am trying to write an algorithm which finds the maximum squared distance between a pair of coordinates from a set of given coordinates.
Note : The coordinates are integers
Let's suppose I have a set of coordinates as ${{a:(1,2),\,b:(2,3), \,c:(3,4)}}$, I naturally took the process of finding the squared distance between each pair;
$$D_{ab} =2$$
$$D_{bc} =2$$
$$D_{ac} =8$$
Here we can easily pick $D_{ac}$ as our maximum squared distance.

Now while trying to write the code for this, I am a little confused as to how to generalize this approach, here's what I tried,
Say we enter in n-coordinates, $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\cdots(x_n,y_n)$.
Our squared distance is defined by; $$D=(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2$$
Now I went for the obvious way which is finding the right conditions which maximizes the above expression using the known inputs from $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\cdots(x_n,y_n)$.
I naturally thought of picking the value of $x_i$ as the largest of the x-coordinates and $x_j$ as the most smallest of the x-coordinates to maximize $(x_i-x_j)^2$.
So I applied the above approach by taking in n-coordinates and then storing all x and y coordinates in two different arrays, and then sorting the x-array using the best sort algorithm; quick sort with time complexity $O(n\,log(n))$, So now I have the advantage of picking the largest and smallest of the x-coordinates, which are present in the last and first position of the array. But this method did not guarantee the maximized value of $D$ when i stored the previous position of the largest and smallest of the x-array and mapped it to the unsorted y-array to keep a track of the y-coordinate associated with the largest and smallest x-coordinate. This method kept failing as i varied the number of coordinates i entered, primarily because of the constraint on picking the y-coordinates this method drastically is flawed, and I am unable to move further.
I would like to mention I am trying my best to keep the time complexity as low as possible, unlike my previous tries where I ran multiple loops and found my maximum distance easily but this is causing a time complexity of $O(n^2)$ or more. I am extremely interested in finding the most optimized algorithm that can solve this problem.

One can generate the convex hull first, which has order $n\log n$ complexity according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms . The final minimization over all pairs then needs to be applied only on the vertices of the convex hull.

@YvesDaoust, in my assignment it is $3\le n \le 100$, does a large upper bound bring difficulties?
